# Set new XML attribute value C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to update an attribute value from the XML file I've created this way :

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Song
    {
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string tittle { get; set; }
    }

    // Main class
    private void bt_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Song s = new Song("Chopin", "Nocturne B minor");
        SaveParametresXml(ref s);
    }

    public void SaveParametresXml(ref Song s)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Song));
        StreamWriter xml = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Tests\mysong.xml", false);
        serializer.Serialize(xml, s);
        xml.Close();
    }
```

Which is working perfectly, I got the following result on my XML file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Song xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <artist>Chopin</artist>
      <tittle>Nocturne B minor</tittle>
    </Song>
```

The problem is that I don't manage to do value modification.
Is there anyone to help me dealing with my XML's problems? I've already tried to `Deserialize` but I do not really get how should I use it?

```
        public Song LoadXml(string path)
        {
            Song s = new Song();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Song));   
            StreamReader xml = new StreamReader(path);     
            s = (Song)xs.Deserialize(xml);                         
            xml.Close();                                          
            return s;                                           
        }
```

Comment: When you deserialize, are you getting a new Song object returned with the values from your XML file?

Comment: Yes I do, I got access to my Song properties by using the s instance like s.artist or s.tittle

Comment: Do you want to access created `Xml` file and modify the values?

Comment: Yes, I tried this : 
`LoadXml(@"E:\Tests\mysong.xml").tittle = "Nocturne D major";`
        But my file is not updated while I don'get get compilation errors